# If the Cartesian product of two sets is dense, does this imply that each of the two sets is also dense?

Tags: general-topology

Let $S_1,S_2\subseteq X$. Suppose $S_1 \times S_2$ is dense in $X^2$. Then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are each dense in $X$. True?

Comment: Suppose $S_1$ were not dense. Can you show that then $S_1\times X$ is not dense?

Answer (score 6):

The projection $p$ onto $X$ is a continuous surjection. In general, if $A$ is dense in $X$ and $f$ is continuous, then $f[A]$ is dense in $f[X]$ since $\overline{f[A]}\supseteq f\left[\overline A\right]=f[X]$.

In your case $p[S_1\times S_2]=S_1$ which is thus dense in $p\left[X^2\right]=X$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U\subset X$ be nonempty open. Then $U\times X$ is a nonempty open subset of  $X\times X$, hence intersects $S_1\times S_2$, i.e. contains some $(s_1,s_2)\in S_1\times S_2$. Then $s_1\in U$, i.e. $U\cap S_1$ is nonempty. This shows that $S_1$ is dense, similary $S_2$ is dense.